# HTML DOM manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, dom

I wonder how I can manipulate the DOM tree using PHP?

I have seen some answers with XML DOM that loads in a html file. But what if I don't need to load? What if have XML DOM scripts inside the document I want to manipulate?

I have an example below that prints out all the folders. Fill in the blanks in your answers. I want to create div-elements with the folder's name as text node. The answer need to have some XML DOM scripts because I will create more elements than just one div-element in my website. And using for example echo is not practical, because you might insert an element inside the wrong element etc.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT name
    FROM folders
    WHERE profileId = '$profileId'
";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error6: '.mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

}
```

Comment: To clarify, is you problem that you're building a string like `<div id=my-id ></div>` in one place, and then somewhere else in the code you want to insert a node into that div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need PHP to manipulate the dom of a document you're generating already. It's by far easier to just have PHP directly generate some HTML. DOM's there to disect/change HTML that was generated elsewhere. In other words, your script would just be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div>{$row['name']}</div>";
}
```

---

DOM example, to demonstrate the tediousness

Ok, here's the PHP method to generate a paragraph of text with some internal spans and whatnot:

```
echo "<div> This is my div, <span>There are many like it, <b>but this one</b> is</span> mine</div>";
```

The equivalent DOM calls: (not tested, just to demonstrate):

```
$dom = new DOM;

$bold = new DOMElement('b');
$bold->appendChild(new DOMText('but this one'));

$span = new DOMElement('span');
$span->appendChild(new DOMText('There are many like it,'));
$span->appendChild($bold);
$span->appendChild(new DOMText(' is');

$div = new DOMElement('div');
$div->appendChild(new DOMText(' This is my div,'));
$div->appendChild($span);
$div->appendChild(' mine');

echo $div->saveXML();
```

So....... still thing using DOM is easier than using `echo`?

Comment: it is to cumbersome to use echo all the time. What if I have more than one div element?

Comment: @Woho: Using echo in PHP to spit out some HTML is much much easier than using DOM calls to build up a document node-by-node. If you have more things to put inside the div, then simply echo out the html snippets. Otherwise you're stuck with about a LONG sequence of "create node", "populate node", "insert node" sequences.

Comment: Using echo is only useful for simple html as building more complex structures, especially in a non-sequential manner, is tedious and error-prone. Also creating elements in simplexml or dom automatically handles encoding entities. Whenever I've used dom, I built several helper functions to do common tasks, like creating an element on another element with multiple attributes. Simplexml is easier to use for most of the legwork in dom building, resorting to dom only to insert isolated elements built with simplexml

Comment: An example of non-sequential dom building is when using a file to hold html while building it semantically over several web round trips. An alternative is to store the content in an xml file while building the structure and generating the html using xsl

Answer (score 3):

For PHP driven DOM manipulation try [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). If you are familiar with jQuery, the similar syntax makes it a good library to use.

Comment: Sadly, phpQuery is now dead. It was my goto for this type of problem. `phpgt/dom` looks promising. See @Greg's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I find using PHP's inbuilt DOM implementation (libxml) very clunky due to it only supporting DOM 2. I prefer using phpgt/dom (https://github.com/phpgt/dom) available [through composer](https://packagist.org/packages/phpgt/dom).

Usage example:

```
$document = new \phpgt\dom\HTMLDocument(
    "<!doctype html><h1>My list of amazing things</h1> <ul class='my-list'></ul>"
);

$result = $database->query("SELECT thing FROM Amazing");
$ul_output = $document->querySelector("ul.my-list");

foreach($result as $row) {
    $li = $document->createElement("li");
    $li->textContent = $row["thing"];
    $ul_output->appendChild($li);
}

echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Full documentation available on the project's Github wiki: https://github.com/phpgt/dom/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error6: '.mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   ?><div><?php echo $result[0]; ?></div><?php
}
```

If this is not what you seek please detail your question by adding what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to use XML DOM in PHP. Because I will create a lot of html elements

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is pre DOM since you are building the page in HTML prior to outputting it to the client at which point it becomes the document object model within the context of the client. Therefore your DOM manipulation is effectively just HTML generation in PHP on the server side.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$sql = "
SELECT name
FROM folders
WHERE profileId = '".mysql_escape_string($profileId)."'
";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error6: '.mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<div>".htmlentities($row['name'])."</div>";
}
?>
</body></html>
```

I have also added mysql_escape_string to your sql statement to help protect from sql injection attacks while using htmlentities on the echo output to help prevent script injection into the page.

Comment: I think in order to answer Woho87's question fully it will be necessary for them to provide an example of the output they are expecting to be sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking that PHP creates a DOM as you echo HTML, that does not happen. However, you can use Marc B samples to generate DOM nodes (that you can append to). After you've manipulated that node,you can then echo the nodes HTML using http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php