# Is it possible to use PHP DOMDocument to manipulate and return an HTML snippet?

Tags: php, html, dom, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Wordpress uses a filter called "the_content" I can hook into that allows me to manipulate the section of HTML that represents the inner contents of the body tag before its rendered. (This is not a wordpress question, I'm just providing context.) That means there is no DOCTYPE declaration.

Here is a snippit of code I'm trying to work with:

```
<div id="x-section-1" > lots of stuff and child divs</div>
```

What I would like to do is find this  and then append a second div immediately after it. I cannot use string replacement / regex because the internal contents of this div change often. The only thing that is constant is the #id.

DOMDocument seems like the logical choice to do this. I've tried:

```
@$doc->loadHTML($content);
$snippet = $doc->getElementById('x-section-1');
```

However, this returns an empty result. Indeed, the PHP comments in the manual for getElementById state that if DOCTYPE isn't defined null is returned.

So based on similar questions on SE I tried DOMXpath:

```
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@id="x-section-1"]');
$div = $div->item(0);
$snippet = $dom->saveXML($div);
```

The problem here is that it returns the entire value of '$content'

Finally, another problem I'm having regardless is that I'm getting weird character formatting. Even though I said that regex / string replacement wasn't an option, that's not entirely true. The weird formatting only happens when I use a '$dom->save' function.  If I can get the value of this div then I can append my new string to the end of it, and then find and replace.

Is it possible to use DOMDocument for this? If so, how? If not, what's another approach?

Note: This questions seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to achieve. However, the difference is that question is loading a full html file, which I'm sure has a DOCTYPE.

[PHP DomDocument HTML Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877802/php-domdocument-html-manipulation)

Comment: Can this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299433/html-dom-manipulation-in-php

Comment: I noticed that thread, but it wasn't apparent to me how any of those questions were loading an existing html block from which to extract the div. As well, if it's true that getElementById must have a doctype declaration to return a value, using DOM may be moot. I don't know how to get the value of that div otherwise

Comment: What about this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491598/how-can-i-get-a-div-content-in-php

Comment: That's very similar to my second attempt. When I follow that question's code exactly I get 'object(DOMNodeList)#2350 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } object(DOMNodeList)#2338 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } So, it's still returning null for me, and I wonder if it's because I'm trying to use getElementById without a doctype.
'

Answer (score 1):

as you mention you want to "append a second div immediately after (x-section-1)" 

     so you could simply use (jQuery/Ajax) for real time Action and avoid all brain Dizziness :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#x-section-1").after("<div id='Second_Div'> YOUR HTML CODE HERE </div>");
});
</script>
```

replace "YOUR HTML CODE HERE" with any html code you want ,
or add **php** code [here][1]

> ***➳  Note*** : if you want to Add Large html code then it most be stick to each-other 
> without "enter space" example:
>  `$("#x-section-1").html('<div id="Second_Div"><label>Users Name:</label></div> <br>');` 
>  or you can separate the lines using `+` like that :
>
> ```
>  $("#x-section-1").after(
>    '<br> <div id="Second_Div">'     +
>    '<form action="" method="post">' +
>    '<label>Users Name:</label>'     +
>    '<br><select name="Users" id="UsersSelect">'  +
>    '<option value="$id"> testUserName </option>' +
>    '</ select></ form></ div>'
>   );
> ```

or you can fill it using **php $string** that contain some data like :

```
<?php 
// your string that can contain anything you want .
 $test_string = "userId is :9000 "; 
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#x-section-1").after(<?php print $test_string; ?>);
});
</script>
```

or you can fill it with both (html + php).

---

and if you want your new code to appear after a (clicked Button) u can use :

```
   $("#your button ID here").click(function(){
    $("#x-section-1").after("<div id='Second_Div'> YOUR HTML CODE HERE </div>");
   });
```

> and dont forget to include [Ajax/jQuery link] in the begening of your page ***IF there is no one*** : 
>    `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`